# npm packges are not install getting error

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to install my npm packages, however I'm getting the following error. What do I need to do to fix this?

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE
npm ERR! typeerror Error: Argument #5: Expected object but got string
npm ERR! typeerror     at inflatableChild (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:93:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at BB.each (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:55:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.gotValue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:155:18)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.gotAccum (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:144:25)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
npm ERR! typeerror     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at _drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
npm ERR! typeerror     at processImmediate (timers.js:637:19)
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user81\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-27T06_37_01_928Z-debug.log
```

Versions:

```
@angular/cli: 1.3.1
node -v v11.9.0
npm -v  6.5.0
```

Comment: Delete the node_modules folder. Run "npm cache clean" and then "npm install".

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

1. I deleted `node_modules` folder.
2. Somehow, `package.lock.json` file is getting created. I deleted that file.
3. Then `npm install`.
4. Clean build.
5. Run.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. Remove node_modules folder

2. open CLI and run `npm cache clean --force`

3. Install npm modules again

4. Run

If issue still exist, then please remove Node from your system. Before removing node, run `npm cache clean --force`. Then restart your system and install compatible node version . If your using Angular 1(Angular JS),then latest node package version will not support it